# Error while creating read only .xlsx file using Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to create one read only Excel-sheet using Apache POI 3.10.

```
private void lockAll(Sheet s, String password) throws Exception{

    XSSFSheet sheet = ((XSSFSheet)s);

     sheet.protectSheet(password);
     sheet.enableLocking();

     sheet.lockSelectLockedCells();
     sheet.lockSelectUnlockedCells();  

}
```

Now I am calling this method after creating my excel sheet using following.

```
private String generateExcel(List<Model> DataList) {
    Workbook wwbook = null;
    File ff = null;
    try {

        String filePath =  // getting this path using ServletContext.
        wwbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        Sheet wsheet = wwbook.createSheet("MyReport");
        ApachePoiExcelFormat xlsxExcelFormat = new ApachePoiExcelFormat();
        CellStyle sheetHeading = xlsxExcelFormat.SheetHeading(wwbook);

        //My personal org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle here.
        short col = 0, row = 0;
        XSSFRow hrow = (XSSFRow) (XSSFRow) wsheet.createRow(row);
        XSSFCell cell = hrow.createCell(col);

        //My code here to iterate List and add data to cell.


        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(filePath.toString());
        wwbook.write(fileOut);
        lockAll(wsheet, "password");   //******calling the method to lock my sheet.
        fileOut.close();

        System.out.println("Excel Created");


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
}
    return filePath;
}
```

Now while I am running this code to download the excel file. Then I am getting error on the webpage but not on my eclipse console.
Next I was trying to run the same code after commenting the following line in lockAll method. And then the excel downloading happens as required, but every cells in the sheet are editable.

```
sheet.protectSheet(password);
```

Comment: I'm curious what exact error you get. But the problem is clear. You first write the Workbook out and then you try to protect a Sheet in that Workbook. You should first protect the Sheet and then write the Workbook out.

Comment: @AxelRichter I have already tried to protect the sheet first. But no luck. What I am not getting is, why there is no error on my eclipse console even though I have catch Exception and Throws Exception too.

Comment: I used your `lockAll()` method in my code and it works for me. If you still get an error, please provide some more info.